# Is there a way to make a UIButton wrap with the text in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uibutton, uilabel

Basically I want the UIButton to appear at the end of a UILabel. The UILabel is localized, so the positioning might vary. Is there a way for me to get the layout just right?

Answer (score -1):

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width - buttonWidth, label.frame.origin.y, buttonHeight, buttonWidth);
```

where `buttonWidth` and `buttonHeight` are just arbitrary variables I put to describe what you should place there

Comment: Should be `label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.width` if you want to get it right.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to add your label and button on the same view. You meant your text is localized and do not know about the size of text until runtime. Actually it is something else what you asked for. Because you need to set the size of the label depends on the size of text. And you can calculate the size of text eg with the following method

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

or you can resize the label after you have set the text like

```
- (void)sizeToFit
```

After you have finished with the size of your label

you can set the frame of you button like

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x + label.frame.size.with, yPosition, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
```

Please note that you need to set the frame of the button after you have set the frame of the label. If you change the frame the label you need to change frame of the button. Or prior ios 6.0 you can use `NSLayoutConstraint` for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html

Comment: An explanation would be great, why I got down vote for my answer?

Answer (score -2):

Set the X value of the button according to the width of label this will set button at right side of the label. now it tested.

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.mylabel.frame.origin.x+self.mylabel.frame.size.width, self.mylabel.frame.origin.y, 50.00, 20.00);
```

[image]

Comment: This will set the button outside of the label's frame

Comment: This assumes that the label origin starts at 0,0 which is not what I want.

Comment: @AnthonyGlyadchenko you have said in your question that `Basically I want the UIButton to appear at the end of a UILabel` and using this code you can see that button display end of the label so what does not worked?

Comment: And it does not assume anything about label this code only take label X,Y value for set the button X,Y value whatever your label's origin value is this code will display button at the end of the label.